# Container docker remains in exited status

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

Hi I'm building a docker image that starts Mysql, Elasticsearch and application, it completes the build of the image but when I run the container it doesn't start and remains in exited status.

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\marco\project\multiple-docker-container\backend
COPY . .
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg -y
RUN wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list'
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install elasticsearch -y
RUN apt install mysql-server -y
RUN apt install npm -y
RUN npm install
RUN npm install nodemon
RUN apt install nodejs -y
EXPOSE 3306
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 5000
COPY entrypoint.sh /bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

ENTRYPOINT.SH

```
#!/bin/sh

service elasticsearch start

service elasticsearch enable

service mysql start

npm start
```

I expect at least that it goes up, I would like to understand which is the problem since on WSL ubuntu gives me this problem while on the virtual machine it works

Comment: You should almost definitely run these in three separate containers, maybe using Docker Compose to tie them all together.  A container is a wrapper around a _single_ process, and commands like `service` often just don't work in Docker for complex reasons (a container is a very different environment from a VM).  It'd be helpful to know what the output of the container is when you run it, and what `npm start` is supposed to actually do (an excerpt from your `package.json` file wold be a key part of a [mcve]).

Comment: in fact I have to do it like this to complete an exercise, if I try to start it in interactive mode it says "exec /bin/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory"

Comment: Is there a chance that the script file has DOS line endings?  That would cause the system to try to run `/bin/sh\r` as the script interpreter, which won't work.

Comment: So how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Delete the script entirely.  In the Dockerfile, set `CMD npm start`.  Run Elasticsearch and MySQL in separate containers.  Docker has a [Use Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/) tutorial that might be a good starting point for setting this up.